# Remove and Add class from <div> and <li> in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <ul class="current">
   <li>
       <a href="#nogo"><b>Products</b>
         <div class="select_sub show">
             <ul class="sub">
              <li class="sub_show"><a href="#nogo">Add product</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
       </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="select">
   <li>
       <a href="#nogo"><b>Item</b>
         <div class="select_sub">
             <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="#nogo">Add Item</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
       </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1.after click Item link  i want to add class in current ul current class and remove form other
it's working by this code

```
$("ul").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

 $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current").addClass("select");

});
```

I have problem with second point

1. When I click item link, I want add class **select_sub show** which div have class select_sub

I mean to say (if i click item link)

```
<ul class="select">
 <li>
   <a href="#nogo"><b>Products</b>
     <div class="select_sub">
         <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#nogo">Add product</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>


<ul class="current">
 <li>
    <a href="#nogo"><b>Item</b>
      <div class="select_sub show">
         <ul class="sub">
          <li class="sub_show"><a href="#nogo">Add Item</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then below should do the trick.

```
$("ul").click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $siblings = $(this).siblings();

    $this.addClass("current"); //probably need to add .removeClass('select')
    $this.find('.select_sub').addClass('show');

    $siblings.removeClass("current").addClass('select');
    $siblings.find('.select_sub').removeClass('show');


});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
$("ul").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".current").addClass("select"); //Add the default "select" class to any "current"
   $(".current").removeClass("current"); //Remove "current" from any "current"
   $(this).removeClass("select"); //Remove "select" from the clicked UL
   $(this).addClass("current"); //Add "current" to the clicked UL
});
```

You can probably call them in 2 lines if you want, but this is easier to read I thought.

Answer (score -1):

Should be as simple as adding:

```
$('.current .select_sub').addClass('show');
```